# Human language based searches in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

Is it possible to make elasticsearch understand human languages?

user types "need a laptop for less than $800 with 8 gb ram" in the searchbox, elasticsearch understands that and filter laptops that have 8gb ram and less than $800?

Are there any packages for this or elasticsearch supports it naturally? Or if it's theoretically possible, any basic idea to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Machine understanding of natural languages is an unsolved problem and is an active area of research, so **the short answer is no, elasticsearch can't be made to understand human languages.**

NLP typically does semantics (understanding) through information extraction which is a sub-field within NLP. Elasticsearch is a great tool, but it not designed for information extraction - it is better thought of as an indexing tool with some extra features. You are likely more interested in named entity recognition (NER) and concept recognition to answer the kind of query you have described of which there is minimal support in Elasticsearch. The problem you are posing is actually a very hard one to answer, which is why Amazon makes available terms like GB on the left hand side of the screen when searching for laptops.

I would start with something other than Elasticsearch, maybe the Stanford NLP toolkit (http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your great answer sir! Is this what google also uses? I mean if you ask a question to google or ask a question to siri, Is this information extraction based things ?

Comment: I suspect in part, but I don't work for Google. Technically what google search does isn't information extraction, it is "document retrieval". They don't actually have to know what a laptop or a GB is, only that the documents they are indexing have those terms. Having said that, I think they probably use information extraction techniques on the search query so they can improve the results of their document retrieval. Hope that helps.